# php dual POST, 1 slash to 4 slashes and back again

Tags: php, post, backslash

i have a question about dual POST methods. I have to get the output to be the exact same as the input. Running on Linux,php v4, and magic quotes on.

1. Input : hello \ ( single slash)
2. First POST: hello\(double backslashes )
3. Second POST: hello \\(quadruple backslashes )
4. Expected: hello \ (Same as input)(single slash)
5. Actual result: hello \(txt file)(double slash)

The first post method are done through form posting, second post by CURL itself. Is it possible to obtain a result of hello\ in the end WITHOUT using stripslashes?

Observations: When saved to a text file, the message was "hello\\" was converted to just "hello\" instead. How does this occur and why, and how do i manipulate the result to show my expected result instead?
P.S for some odd reasons the slashes are not appearing, added descriptions.
Regards.
P.S if it is my coding problem, give me a moment to post it up.

Comment: The title sounds like a horror movie!

Comment: Upgrade your PHP installation immediately!  PHP 4 is obsolete and has been for years.  It's unmaintained and full of security holes.  Also, turn magic_quotes_gpc off.

Answer (score 0):

PHP addslashes() and stripslahes() can be of use to you. use them however you need them between those steps.

http://php.net/addslashes

The reason why you're losing a slash is because the backslash is an escape character, telling the processor to take the next character literally. So to print a backslash, you need to escape a backslash (double backslash \ becomes => single backslash )

Cheers!
Dan